# Regular expression regex to retrieve fields in double quotes from lines

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a file with several lines like that (below two example lines):

```
any_string,N/A,Input,1,1,1,06/13/2019 17:14:04,1560456844,8361,Error loading row to target table [any_string]. Error message [
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (""any_string"".""any_string"".""any_string"")],2,""12345678"";""1234"";""0"";""123456789"";""12"";""123456789123"";""3"";""12345"";""87654321"";""12345"";""any_string"";""1"";"""";""1"";"""";"""";"""",N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
```

I need a shell script to extract from the two lines above the only following excerpt to write in another file:

```
""12345678"";""1234"";""0"";""123456789"";""12"";""123456789123"";""3"";""12345"";""87654321"";""12345"";""any_string"";""1"";"""";""1"";"""";"""";""""
```

I would appreciate any tips of regex to accomplish the task.
input:

```
any_string,N/A,Input,1,1,1,06/13/2019 17:14:04,1560456844,8361,Error loading row to target table [any_string]. Error message [
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (""any_string"".""any_string"".""any_string"")],2,""12345678"";""1234"";""0"";""123456789"";""12"";""123456789123"";""3"";""12345"";""87654321"";""12345"";""any_string"";""1"";"""";""1"";"""";"""";"""",N/A,N/A,-1,-1,N/A
```

expected output:

```
""12345678"";""1234"";""0"";""123456789"";""12"";""123456789123"";""3"";""12345"";""87654321"";""12345"";""any_string"";""1"";"""";""1"";"""";"""";""""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '/"/{print $(NF-5)}' file
""12345678"";""1234"";""0"";""123456789"";""12"";""123456789123"";""3"";""12345"";""87654321"";""12345"";""any_string"";""1"";"""";""1"";"""";"""";""""
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to better describe your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ed ! That's exactly what I need